# leaked window in facebook activity

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, facebook-sdk-4.0

when i am using facebook login button in my activity, logcat shows up this. I don't get it why this showing up I checked entire class never found a reference.

```
06-27 14:17:45.819  12019-12019/com.ets.medecord E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.facebook.FacebookActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4054a518 that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.facebook.FacebookActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4054a518 that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:259)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
            at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:465)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
            at com.facebook.internal.WebDialog$DialogWebViewClient.onPageStarted(WebDialog.java:500)
            at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:264)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

to check out activity code http://pastebin.com/qQqbvX6g

Comment: A `WindowLeaked` error is thrown when you `finish()` an activity that has a dialog currently visible. Are you launching a dialog from your activity that is hosting the Facebook login button? Also are there any errors in logical prior to `android.view.WindowLeaked` being thrown?

Comment: @marcus.ramsden you can checkout my activity's code at http://pastebin.com/qQqbvX6g

Answer (score 0):

Window leak exception often occurs if Dialog not used properly(such as not finished before jumping to another activity). And Google has reminded developers that DialogFragment is a better choice than Dialog.